# Беспроводной адаптер не работает

Tags: linux, wifi, mxlinux

у меня не работает беспроводной адаптер на линуксе.
Linux MX.
Адаптер Tenda U1
Сколько раз не пытался скомпилировать драйвер(или скачать) он не работает, в компиляции выдаёт ошибки, а в установленном режиме выдаёт ошибку. Пытался гуглить, сидел часов пять. При подключении к wifi выдавало:

```
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="HUAWEI-fIfD"
<3>SME: Trying to authenticate with (HERE MAC ADRESS) (SSID='HUAWEI-fIfD' freq=2452 MHz)
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="HUAWEI-fIfD" auth_failures=3 duration=46 reason=CONN_FAILED
```

Вот я пытаюсь скомпилировать:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-1-common/scripts/Makefile.build:310: ошибка  выполнения рецепта для цели «/home/vladdg/rtl8xxxu/rtl8xxxu_core.o»
make[4]: *** [/home/vladdg/rtl8xxxu/rtl8xxxu_core.o] Ошибка 1
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-1-common/Makefile:1532: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «_module_/home/vladdg/rtl8xxxu»
make[3]: *** [_module_/home/vladdg/rtl8xxxu] Ошибка 2
Makefile:146: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «sub-make»
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Ошибка 2
Makefile:8: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «all»
make[1]: *** [all] Ошибка 2
make[1]: выход из каталога «/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-1-amd64»
Makefile:14: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «modules»
make: *** [modules] Ошибка 2
```

Вот lspci -k(не нашёл свой адаптер вовсе):

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
```

А вот inxi -N:

```
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet driver: r8169 
       Device-2: Realtek type: USB driver: rtl8xxxu
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

добавить non-free к основному репозиторию

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
```

потом

```
apt update
apt install firmware-realtek firmware-linux
```

и перезагрузиться. Если не поможет

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

добавить бакпорты

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free
```

потом

```
apt update
apt install --t stretch-backports firmware-realtek firmware-linux linux-image-amd64
```